# Label update on change of Slider Value

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I Have a Java FXML Project. It has a Slider from 1 to 10 with steps of 1. I have a Label.

[image]

Slider = `sl_test`

Label = `txt_test`

I want the the Label to update on every change of the Slider to display the current Value (which i know, i can get with `sl_test.getValue()`).

Comment: `label.textProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty().asString())`..?

Comment: [Using JavaFX UI Controls: Slider](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/slider.htm) has an example; [JavaFX 8 Event Handling Examples](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-event-handling-examples/) would probably also help and [Slider value property change listener](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/Slidervaluepropertychangelistener.htm) certainly couldn't hurt

Answer (score 1):

thanks to the comment from @Slaw i got it

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    txt_test.textProperty().bind(sl_test.valueProperty().asString());
}
```